# Push notification from Notification Hub not working but in FCM it is working

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I have configured my Notification Hub with FCM and have configured my Android mobile app (running in Emulator) to receive notifications. The issue I face here is, If I send test notification from FCM I am getting the notification in Emulator but If I am sending the notification from Azure Notification Hub I am not getting the notification. I have configured as advised by the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started) (Assigned API Key with server key and legacy key). Also, I see that the Registration ID in the Test Notification is the registration ID of the running emulator also.

So what should I check now here? so that I can make notification work from Azure Notification Hub?

Comment: Hi.... Have you tested form Azure Portal or via your code ?

Comment: I tested from Azure Portal - Notification Hub. Even in Firebase, I tested in FCM website

Comment: any solution???

Answer (score 0):

Are you using HTTP Trigger for triggering azure notification hub?

Because HTTP Trigger doesn't support FCM, it supports GCM (which is depreceated one)

So, Trigger Android using FCM